# Pandas select consistent changes without iteration

Tags: python, pandas, select, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
In [9]: d = pd.DataFrame({'place': ['home', 'home', 'home', 'home', 'office', 'office', 'office', 'home', 'office', 'home', 'office', 'home', 'office', 'home'], 'person': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c'], 'other_stuff': ['f', 'g', 'd', 'q', 'w', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'l', 'm', 'n']})



In [7]: d
      place  other_stuff person
 0     home           f      a
 1     home           g      a
 2     home           d      a
 3     home           q      a
 4   office           w      a
 5   office           r      a
 6   office           s      a
 7     home           t      b
 8   office           u      b
 9     home           v      c
 10  office           w      c
 11    home           l      c
 12  office           m      c
 13    home           n      c
```

There are only two `place` categories in my data: `home` and `office`. I want to select the rows of this dataframe that correspond to all `person` who have "permanent transitions" in the `place` column. i.e., I want to select only the `persons` who have changes in their `place` and don't change back.

In this example dataframe, I want to select all rows corresponding to `person` a and `person` b, but not person c. The desired output is:

```
      place  other_stuff person
 0     home           f      a
 1     home           g      a
 2     home           d      a
 3     home           q      a
 4   office           w      a
 5   office           r      a
 6   office           s      a
 7     home           t      b
 8   office           u      b
```

I plan to `groupby` on the column `person`, and then write a function to `apply` to each group of observations. My dataframe has about 60 million rows and 700,000 unique `persons`, so I do not want to use any kind of iteration. 
I'm not sure how to write a function that will select the correct rows without iterating through each group of `person` observations.

Comment: @chrisz Err that misses the point, no?

Comment: This assumes I know all of the persons who have "transitions". But my real dataframe has close to 1 million unique person ids, so this is not generalizable

Comment: I don't understand why you think iteration is a bad idea in regards to the size of the data. In pandas all the data is already in memory anyway. Moreover no matter which algorithm you choose it will have the complexity a least O(N) (same as a single iteration). If you are so concerned about the size of your data an iteration over the data will actually be a good idea. Especially if you load the data in a lazy way.

Comment: The accepted answer may be not the correct one because if you add a new line to you DataFrame where person 'c' change to 'office' you will get only persons 'a' and 'b' as the answer.

Comment: @Ivanovitch, that is what I want -- even with an additional line to person 'c', I should get only the rows for persons 'a' and 'b'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `groupby` `shift`, create the subgroup of each person by the place changes, if it change more than twice , then we should not keep the whole group in the new dataframe

```
s=df.groupby('person').apply(lambda   x : (x['place'].shift()!=x['place']).cumsum().nunique())

df.loc[df.person.isin(s[s<=2].index)]



    place other_stuff person
0    home           f      a
1    home           g      a
2    home           d      a
3    home           q      a
4  office           w      a
5  office           r      a
6  office           s      a
7    home           t      b
8  office           u      b
```

Comment: Would your solution outperform [an iteration + a hashmap of place changes] in terms of CPU and memory usage? I don't know what pandas is doing behind the scenes, but it feels like it's allocating quite a lot of tables (groups, shifts, isin). Am I right?

Answer (score 3):

In each group count the number of times a person has moved.  If one or less, then return true else false and don't get those records.

Use:

```
d[d.groupby('person')['place'].transform(lambda x: (x != x.shift(-1).ffill()).sum())<=1]
```

Output:

```
    place person other_stuff
0    home      a           f
1    home      a           g
2    home      a           d
3    home      a           q
4  office      a           w
5  office      a           r
6  office      a           s
7    home      b           t
8  office      b           u
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the list of person who has their current place different from beginning.

```
g = d.groupby('person')
c = pd.DataFrame(g.first()!=g.last())
list_person = c.loc[c['place']==True].index
d.loc[d['person'].isin(list_person)]
```

Output:

```
   place    other_stuff person
0   home    f             a
1   home    g             a
2   home    d             a
3   home    q             a
4   office  w             a
5   office  r             a
6   office  s             a
7   home    t             b
8   office  u             b
```